# Eigenvalues of a Real Symmetric Bilinear Form Independent of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question is from Artin's *Algebra*, p. 263.

> If $A$ is the matrix of a symmetric bilinear form, prove or disprove: The eigenvalues of $A$ are independent of the choice of basis.

I suspect the result is true.

Real & Symmetric $\Rightarrow$ Hermitian

Then by Corollary (4.12) the matrices which represent the same hermitian form are $= QAQ^*$, where $Q\in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Does this mean that all of these matrices are similar? If so I would be done
since similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: after reading about sylvester's law I suspect such matrices only have the same number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues

Comment: If a matrix is symmetric, it's Hermitian.

Comment: I just wrote up a counter-example in [question 96904](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96904). Compare the starting and the last matrices' eigenvalues.

Comment: If the question does not mean a similarity transformation by *change of basis* that is by the way.

Answer (score 8):

I interpret the question as follows:

Let $f$ be a symmetric bilinear form on a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$ whose characteristic in not two and which has at least four elements, and let $A$ be the matrix of $f$ with respect to some basis $B$ of $V$. Prove or disprove: The eigenvalues of $A$ are independent of the choice of $B$.

We **disprove** the statement as follows.

Putting 
$$
V:=K,\quad f(x,y):=xy,\quad B:=\{b\},
$$
we get $A=(b^2)$. In view of the assumptions on $K$, we can choose nonzero $b$ and $b'$ in $K$ so that $b^2\neq b'^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you regard those $Q$ as change of basis, then only rigid transformations (isometries/preserving the inner product) preserve eigenvalue. Otherwise if you scale the principal axes like Gaillard does in his answer - $b\neq b’$ - the bilinear form applies a quadratic effect which alters the eigenvalue.
Pratically you need $Q$ to be unitary.